Looping over a variable number of columns in a dataframe
I want to speed up my row loop in a Pandas DataFrame, using the zip columns trick, like this:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [0,1], "b": [2,3]})
for a, b in zip(df["a"], df["b"]):
    pass

The dataframe has a variable number of columns. How can I unpack the row tuple into a, b, c, etc.?

What is the main question? Is your question about unpacking unknown number of columns after calling zip on them?

yes that's correct

I can say how to do it, but what is the main purpose of doing so? Only speeding up?

yes, this is purely to speed up the loop.

Here is one of the possible ways of doing so, you can create a list of Series from your DataFrame like this :
columns = [df[col] for col in df]

Then you can unpack this list and use it inside a loop.
for item in zip(*columns):
    print(item)

The output will be like this :
(0, 2)
(1, 3)

Which contains each row as a tuple.

thank you. Is there any way to have a named variable based on the column name in the df?

Does it have to have a name? because if it is necessary, you can use itertuples and get variable by their name

I know, but itertuples is slow. I guess there's no easy way to do it. thanks

You can use the * operator to unpack the row tuple into individual variables. Here's how you can modify your loop to achieve this:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [0, 1], "b": [2, 3], "c": [4, 5]})  # Adding an extra column for demonstration
for row in df.itertuples(index=False):
    a, b, c, *others = row
    # Now you can use a, b, c, etc. in your loop
    print(a, b, c)  # Example: print the values

This will automatically unpack each row tuple into the variables a, b, c, etc., regardless of the number of columns in your DataFrame.
